# Converting C# encryption to C++ encryption

Tags: c++, encryption

I am currently learning C++ and looking into using it for a project but I need to be able to encrypt and decrypt string.

I have conversion code in various languages such as C#, Java and PHP and they can work together, for example, C# and/or/ Java and/or PHP can write an encrypted string to a database and any of those languages can read in the value from the database and decrypt it.

Below is the C# code as an example:

```
public static string encrypt(string encryptionString)
        {
            byte[] clearTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionString);

            SymmetricAlgorithm rijn = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ryojvlzmdalyglrj");

            byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hcxilkqbbhczfeultgbskdmaunivmfuo");
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rijn.CreateEncryptor(key, rgbIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            cs.Write(clearTextBytes, 0, clearTextBytes.Length);

            cs.Close();

            return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
```

I have tried the following in C++

```
void Encryption::encryptString(string stringToEncrypt)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);

    //string key = "hcxilkqbbhczfeultgbskdmaunivmfuo";
    //string iv = "ryojvlzmdalyglrj";

    unsigned char key[33] = "hcxilkqbbhczfeultgbskdmaunivmfuo";
    unsigned char iv[17] = "ryojvlzmdalyglrj";



    vector<unsigned char> encrypted;
    size_t max_output_len = stringToEncrypt.length() + 16 - (stringToEncrypt.length() % 16);
    //size_t max_output_len = 16 - (stringToEncrypt.length() % 16);
    encrypted.resize(max_output_len);

    EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv, 1);

    // EVP_CipherUpdate can encrypt all your data at once, or you can do
        // small chunks at a time.
        int actual_size = 0;
    EVP_CipherUpdate(&ctx,
        &encrypted[0], &actual_size,
        reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&stringToEncrypt[0]), stringToEncrypt.size());

    // EVP_CipherFinal_ex is what applies the padding.  If your data is
    // a multiple of the block size, you'll get an extra AES block filled
    // with nothing but padding.
    int final_size;
    EVP_CipherFinal_ex(&ctx, &encrypted[actual_size], &final_size);
    actual_size += final_size;

    encrypted.resize(actual_size);

    for (size_t index = 0; index < encrypted.size(); ++index)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') <<
            static_cast<unsigned int>(encrypted[index]);
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
}
```

Although the code runs, I get a completely different response.

For example in C++ I get `bb5ef912a40cb9f16b91b3a7fccc2bc8` whereas if I encrypt `Hello` in any of the other languages I have I get `u175EqQMufFrkbOn/MwryA==`

I have linked the project to the openssl libraries

### Update

I was a bit of a numpty, didn't notice the string was converted to hex and I wasn't 100% sure whether or not the openssl encryptor does the base 64 encoding or not.

So I am now trying to convert what has been encrypted into a base 64 string.

Below is the C++ encoding code that does the encoding:

```
string HelperMethods::base64Encode(const char* buffer, int in_len)
{
std::string ret;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    unsigned char char_array_3[3];
    unsigned char char_array_4[4];

    while (in_len--) {
        char_array_3[i++] = *(buffer++);
        if (i == 3) {
            char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
            char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
            char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
            char_array_4[3] = char_array_3[2] & 0x3f;

            for (i = 0; (i < 4); i++)
                ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[i]];
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (i)
    {
        for (j = i; j < 3; j++)
            char_array_3[j] = '\0';

        char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
        char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
        char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
        char_array_4[3] = char_array_3[2] & 0x3f;

        for (j = 0; (j < i + 1); j++)
            ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[j]];

        while ((i++ < 3))
            ret += '=';

    }

    return ret;
}
```

When I am encrypting the string `Hello` I am expectin the base 64 encoded string to be `u175EqQMufFrkbOn/MwryA==` but when I run it in the C++ code I am getting the following:

`u175EqQMufFrkbOn/MwryADNzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc39/f39NjQAAA==`

As you can see, I'm more a less there, except its for some reason a lot bigger than I was expecting, `NZc3` seems to keep repeating itself for some reason.

I am calling the encoder as follows from the encryption function

```
char * buff_str = (char*)malloc(encrypted.size() * 2 + 1);
    char * buff_ptr = buff_str;


    for (size_t index = 0; index < encrypted.size(); ++index)
    {
        buff_ptr += sprintf(buff_ptr, "%c", encrypted[index]);

    }
    string encryptedString = buff_str;


    HelperMethods helperMethods;
    string converted = helperMethods.base64Encode(encryptedString.c_str(), sizeof(encryptedString));
    cout << "Converted: " << converted << endl;
```

Comment: What encryption algorithm does `SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();` instantiate?

Comment: @RichardCritten Rijndael https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z851sbdb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @OP: What you get in C++ is not Base64.

Comment: I was wondering what, I copied the string into a base64 encoder but it gave me `YmI1ZWY5MTJhNDBjYjlmMTZiOTFiM2E3ZmNjYzJiYzg=`. The encoder I used was `https://www.base64encode.org/`

Comment: @LightnessRaceinOrbit Good, I don't even understand this sentence... Whatever. Comments removed, apologized, hopefully that's all.

Comment: Try tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en (or just write it yourself in your program). Your link does convert plain data (not hex) to base64.

Comment: Crikey, wasn't expecting to cause an argument, I did mention about wondering whether it was because of base64, wasn't 100% sure whether the openssl libs would do it itself, I did wonder that, admitiddely in the comments meant to in the question but still

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know that word, thank you. Before it gets even more offtopic, I'm out of this thread.

Comment: @deviantfan: Okay. It's just that you said a minute ago you didn't understand it, so I thought I would help you. Glad we're on the same page. Have a nice day!

Comment: Is there one, I looked for one but everything I googled was people writing their own methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply: the result of the encryption is the same, they are just in different encodings. `bb5ef912a40cb9f16b91b3a7fccc2bc8` is [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) encoded and `u175EqQMufFrkbOn/MwryA==` is [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded. They are the same value.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question, I have a prob with the base64 encoding.

Comment: Ah sussed it, I did sizeof(string) instead of string.length()

Answer (score 1):

About the Base64 part:
Replace

```
char * buff_str = (char*)malloc(encrypted.size() * 2 + 1);
    char * buff_ptr = buff_str;


    for (size_t index = 0; index < encrypted.size(); ++index)
    {
        buff_ptr += sprintf(buff_ptr, "%c", encrypted[index]);

    }
    string encryptedString = buff_str;


    HelperMethods helperMethods;
    string converted = helperMethods.base64Encode(encryptedString.c_str(), sizeof(encryptedString));
    cout << "Converted: " << converted << endl;
```

with

```
HelperMethods helperMethods;
string converted = helperMethods.base64Encode(encrypted.data(), encrypted.size());
cout << "Converted: " << converted << endl;
```